# What is the steel used for CHC DIN912 class 12.9 exagonal bolt?

Tags: solid-mechanics

I would like to know which steel is used for CHC class 12.9 bolt DIN912 (i am looking for the young modulous & poisson ratio of the material).

Thanks a lot.

Alexandre

Comment: I would be very surprised if I found out that the standard demands a specific steel. In any case, the steels that can be used for a 12.9 bold should not exhibit any significant differences in Young's modulus. *If* there is any change, it should be on the Poisson ratio, however even there it should be in the range between 0.27 and 0.31.

Comment: It could be an alloy steel equivalent to ASTM F568M (ISO898-1). If so, its properties can be found here. https://www.steelestores.com/grade/astm-f568-class-129-astm-f568m.html

Answer (score 0):

I found this :
https://www.fullerfasteners.com/tech/steels-for-screws-bolts-and-studs/

So I used 37CR4 and I found density & young modulous here : https://steelselector.sij.si/steels/37CR4.html

Comment: Steel is steel; in this application about the only difference is strength . The influence of alloy is on hardenability  . Hardenability determines how fast it must be quenched and how large the diameter can be ( for full hardness )  ; then alloy affects tempering temperature. Bottom line , all steels of strength "X"  have very similar properties regardless of particular alloy .

Answer (score 0):

I think all the DIN standards are now ISO. Here are references I found:

Corresponding ISO standard, primary source --
[ISO 898-1:2013](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:898:-1:ed-5:v1:en)

[PDF copy of ISO 898-1:2013](http://www.bsf-sh.com/upload/file/20160601/20160601090559885988.pdf) from google search

To indirectly address the OP question, see document sections 6 (Materials), and 7 (Mechanical Properties).

The document specifies a a bunch of of properties like strength and hardness, but not Young's modulus or Poisson ratio -- although these are implicitly constrained by the material composition as per NMech's comment above.